# How to use multiple paths for Python modules documentation in different directories using Sphinx autodoc?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am using Sphinx `autodoc` to document Python modules in multiple directories. I already have the rst files for each Python module and can use `autodoc` when declaring a path to one directory with the Python modules but I am trying to document Python modules from two different directories. In the `conf.py` file, I used:

`sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../python_modules_A"))`

but would like to have a path to both `python_modules_A` and `python_modules_B`, since my modules are in both directories.

Given the structure of my project team, I would like to avoid having to restructure the modules into one directory since they are separated by helper functions in `python_modules_A` and main objects/classes in `python_modules_B`

Below is how my directories are configured:

```
sphinx_documentation_setup
  conf.py
  index.rst
  a1.rst
  b1.rst
  a2.rst
  b2.rst
python_modules_A
  a1.py
  b1.py
python_modules_B
  a2.py
  b2.py
```

Comment: You can have more than one `sys.path.insert(...)` line in conf.py.

Comment: I declared two paths in my conf.py, one for python_modules_A and python_modules_B but when I run make.html, sphinx only recognizes the first path listed and ignores the second. For example, I list sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../python_modules_A")) first then, sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../python_modules_B)), but get import errors for every python modules in the python_modules_B directory.

Comment: I think a [mcve] is needed. For one thing, what do your `automodule` directives look like exactly?

Comment: Ah just found a solution to my problem, I listed out what my automodule directives look like in the answer below. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Just figured out a solution. I was able to fix the problem by specifying the path in the automodule directives. For example, beforehand my automodule directives were as follows:

```
.. automodule:: a1
.. automodule:: a2
```

but when I switched it to

```
.. automodule:: python_modules_A.a1
.. automodule:: python_modules_B.a2
```

and declared the pathway in the conf.py as:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(".."))
```

sphinx was able to find my python modules in both directories.

Comment: For me this doesn't look like the correct solution. You configure it as if your modules were submodules: `python_modules_A` being a top-level module (which should usually contain `__init__.py`), and `a1` being its submodule. Is it really what you want to achieve?
PS. I know it is an old answer, but someone else might stumble upon it.